# Would the existence of leptoquarks solve the hierarchy problem of the Higgs-boson?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model, fine-tuning

Would the existence of leptoquarks solve the hierarchy problem of the Higgs-boson ? According to wikipedia these are assumed to be bosons which could contribute to the cancellation of the vacuum polarization generated by the fermions.

Comment: Link to the article? If the leptoquarks are "leftovers" of a theory which (partially) solves the hierarchy problem e.g. compositeness, then I can see a link. But in general no, leptoquarks do not solve the hierarchy problem.

Comment: I read an article in the CERN-courier that several decays measured at LHCb do not correspond to the SM expectation. The evidence is still not achieved, it's not a $5\sigma$ effect. If this effect is persistent with more statistics the explanation of the SM-deviation could be lepto-quarks. As these are massive bosons they could couple via Yukawa-coupling to the Higgs & counteract the coupling effect of the fermions to the Higgs. Is this idea wrong ? If the Lepto-quarks couple in the same way to the Higgs as all massive SM-particles do this should work out, no ? Could you say more about it ?

Comment: Yes, B-physics anomalies seen at LHCb and other experiments can indeed be explained by the presence of particular leptoquarks. I fail to see the link with the hierarchy problem though, unless the complete theory which provides these leptoquarks addresses the hierarchy problem (e.g. compositness). The leptoquarks could well come from non-supersymmetric Grand Unified Theories, and that would simply make the hierarchy problem worse instead of solving it..